# "this.state" or methods are not accessible in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have sample code to generate tree. But it shows errors that `this.state.action` or `this.onClickNode` is undefined while I've defined all of them in constructor.

```
export default class TreeList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {tree: tree, action: null}
    this.onClickNode = this.onClickNode.bind(this)
  }
  onClickNode(node) {
    this.setState({active: node})
  }
  renderNode(node) {
    console.log(this.state.action)
    return (
      <span onClick={this.onClickNode(null, node)}>
        {node.module}
      </span>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tree tree={this.state.tree} renderNode={this.renderNode}/>
      </div>
   )
 }
```

}

I've used this library: https://pqx.github.io/react-ui-tree/

Comment: You probably need to bind `this` for your `this.renderNode` function e.g `this.renderNode = this.renderNode.bind(this)`

Comment: the state isn't accessible via `onClickNode` ? btw you know that you are settings `this.state.action` to `null` instead of `node` because this is your first param inside `onClickNode` ..

Comment: @Ido yes it's null and it should return "null", but it returns undefined instead.

Comment: You set the state tree to tree? What is tree? I think that tree is undefined when you try to set your state.

Comment: @Boky `tree` is a variable name which contains dictionary. it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `this` to your `renderNode` function because `this` is [not automatically bound](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#autobinding) for ES6 classes. Otherwise, you will not have the appropriate context in your function. This is why your `this.state.action` is undefined and why it can't resolve `this.onClickNode`.

In your constructor, add

```
this.renderNode = this.renderNode.bind(this);
```

Also, if you want to use node in your onClick handler, you can switch it to

```
  onClickNode(firstParam, node) {
    return (event) => {
        this.setState({active: node})
     }
  }
```

I'm assuming that what's happening is that `this.renderNode` executes when `render()` is called which then is executing `this.onClickNode` and then updates the `state`. Well, since `state` is updated, it'll call `render()` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I defined `this.renderNode = this.renderNode.bind(this);` it will goes to infinity loop and my browser will get crashed.

Comment: @Mortezaipo I also noticed that your `onClick` handler is executing a function `this.onClickNode(null, node)` and not just passing a reference to the function. You should probably have `this.onClickNode` return a function that then contains your `node` object. This could be the source of your infinite loop.

Comment: So I should add this instead: `onClick={this.onClickNode}` ?